# Having issues with multiple hidden/revealed DIVs using JQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am currently creating a page for a website where there will be a vertical navigation bar, and upon clicking on the menu items/submenu items on said navigation bar, different DIVs will be hidden/revealed, showing and hiding different products.

So far, I have gotten the showing/hiding of the main menu items to work upon clicking them.

Example:
I click on the "First Item" link at the top of the menu, and a grid of First Item images show up next to the navigation bar. Then I click on "Second Menu Item", and the first images vanish, and the Second Item images appear, etc.

However, where I have run into some trouble is, for some reason, when I click on one of the submenu items, its images show up, but I can't get the corresponding main menu item's images to disappear.

Here's the code for main menu/sub menu issue:

HTML

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li class="item1">
        <a href="#">Product Category 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Sub 1 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<!---HIDDEN DIVS--->

<div id='hidden_div' >
    <img src="images/item1.png"/>
</div>
<div id='hidden_div2' >
    <img src="images/item1.png"/>
</div>
```

JQUERY FOR SHOWING AND HIDING

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.item1').click(function() 
    {
        $('#hidden_div').show();
        $('#hidden_div2').hide();
    });

    $('.sub1').click(function() 
    {
        $('#hidden_div2').show();
        $('#hidden_div').hide();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if the navigation bar Javascript is the problem, but the only Javascript file connected to this page is minimized...say the word and I can post the code. I don't know, I'm lost.

Comment: Actually, just realized now, that the photos corresponding with ".sub1" don't go away once I've selected it either. Even when I click on a non-corresponding/parenting main menu item afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that the `.sub1` is inside `.item1`, so when you click on `.sub1` you also click on `.item1`.

That is called event bubbling. To stop that, just use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on your `.sub1` click like that :

```
$('.sub1').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#hidden_div2').show();
    $('#hidden_div').hide();
});
```

If you dont want to use `stopPropagation` you could also just change you selector to `$('.item1>a)` and `$('.sub1>a')`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thank you so much. I would vote this up, but apparently I don't have enough of a reputation yet or something haha

Answer (score 0):

It was your HTML actually that was screwing it up.  You have a hanging `<li>` tag for Product 1 that extends past product 2.  This is why your clicks are always running the first bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/6wE52/